# Refreshing pdf with AucTeX doesn't work

Tags: pdf, auctex

I'm running Emacs 27.1 on OSX. `C-c C-a` builds my xelatex source just fine. However, when I make incremental changes to my sources and re-run `C-c C-a`, the generated pdf does not display these changes. Exiting Preview and running `C-c C-a` doesn't help either. Is this a real issue? I'd like to know if a different set of keystrokes will get the job done.

Comment: This usually depends on your pdf viewer program.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using OSX's Preview. When I run `xelatex myfile.tex` from the terminal and switch back to the pdf, I see that its contents get refreshed. However, this doesn't happen when i compile it from emacs.